# What is Varys' endgame for the realm according to the show?

Tags: game-of-thrones

What is Varys' endgame for the realm according to the show?

Comment: @Beofett Obviously, but what do your deductions (Game Theory) suggest to you what the endgame may be?

Comment: @Beofett I appreciate the fencesitting, but ardentsonata has tangible proof.

Comment: We are still two books away from the series' end, and we have yet to get a glimpse into Varys's head (via POV chapter ideally), so I think answering this question will be pure speculation. See my comment on ardentsonata's answer. VTC.

Comment: @SystemDown I am completely satisfied with ardensonata's answer as it does reveal another variable in Vary's "game." So, yes, it gives us a glimpse, and since when did the dictionary and every academic pursuit postulate that deduction is the same as speculation?!

Comment: I think it is interesting to note the similarities between Egg, Bloodraven, Shiera Seastar and Varys.

Comment: @Beofett Last point of clarification: in the book "The Philosophy of Game of Thrones" it states (in the chapter entitled 'Game Theory in Game of Thrones') that the games Tyrion and Varys play can actually demonstrate a probable endgame based on a SINGLE (yes, SINGLE) variable. Thus, ardentsonata presented a constant variable from which we can come to the most probable resolution.

Comment: @Beofett If you cannot rationalize that every cause has an underlying motive, and various motives reveal intent/endgame then all hope for this discussion is lost. Read the book i've mentioned twice and perhaps you will understand how qualitative variables, like motives, can enable anyone to DEDUCE a probable outcome free of arm-chair philosophy. Finally, once you have come up with the highest probability then perhaps, PERHAPS, you can discover the intentions which when added up will reveal what he considers to be the good. However, this requires an "active" and not "passive" analysis.

Comment: @Mariovingian I'm not sure I agree. The speculation you propose IS highly interesting, but it's just that: speculation. It's also not based on established canon (is "The Philosophy of Game of Thrones" canon?). At this stage we simply _do not know_ what Varys' endgame is. We simply cannot know. Maybe he is a Targaryen supporter. Maybe he is an alien supporting a hive mind. Only GRRM knows for certain, and he hasn't told us yet. (I'm willing to agree it's _likely_ he is a Targaryen supporter after all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are definitely spoilers if you haven't read the books yet, but to Varys:

> The good of the realm is putting a Targaryen back on the throne. This is evidenced by him killing Kevan Lannister and Grand Maester Pycelle while saying that he was grooming Aegon Targaryen for the throne.

Thus all his plans revolve around this.

Comment: But is this indeed his ultimate goal? Or is it just another means to an end?

Comment: @SystemDown I don't necessarily know if it is his ultimate goal per say. But based on the wording of OP's question, Varys does specifically say it is for the good of the realm for spoiler deaths and spoiler plan to happen.

Comment: @SystemDown  You state "...another means to an end?" Based on what I wrote earlier about the book "The Philosophy of Game of Thrones" it states (in the chapter entitled 'Game Theory in Game of Thrones') that if one extrapolates the various "means/games" then we can graduate from opinions and speculations to hypotheses!

Comment: I don't think the character you mentioned for grooming is on the show (or not the one you actually meant).